# How to migrate a catkin workspace?

Tags: catkin, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just upgraded my VM from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04, and my ROS installation from Hydro to Indigo.

Now that I've done that, I wonder if there is anything special I need to do to migrate my catkin workspace (which was created initially with Hydro) to Indigo.

I just tried the obvious (I guess I could have tried this *before* I asked my question, but the end result was about what I expected):

```
$ source catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash 
$ cd catkin_ws/
$ catkin_make
catkin_make: command not found
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193901/how-to-migrate-a-catkin-workspace?/) by [wpd](https://answers.ros.org/users/19918/wpd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 249 on 2014-09-30

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Now that I've done that, I wonder if there is anything special I need to do to migrate my catkin workspace (which was created initially with Hydro) to Indigo.

tl;dr: remove the `devel/` and `build/` directories from your `catkin_ws/`. Remove `src/CMakeLists.txt`. Then:

```
source /opt/ros/DISTRO/setup.bash
cd catkin_ws/
catkin_make
```

---

Anytime you move a `catkin_ws/` directory, it is recommended to remove the `devel/` and `build/` directories. Files in those dirs (may) contain references to the old location(s) of build artefacts, which, after moving your workspace, has just changed.

Changing between ROS distributions is similar, in that the `build/` and `devel/` directories contain references to the location(s) of several key binaries, paths and environment variables that (may) have changed. Additionally, the `src/` directory should contain a `CMakeLists.txt` symlink, which points (in your case) to the Hydro version. This should be updated as well. Remove it and invoke `catkin_make` in your `catkin_ws/`: the link will be recreated automatically.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-10-01**:
I guess a catkin_init_workspace in the catkin_ws/src will be necessary as well; because the prior sym link to top_level cmakelists of hydro distribution will no longer be valid....

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-10-01**:
@Wolf, yes, that is probably true. I've updated my answer.

**Comment by [wpd](https://answers.ros.org/users/19918/wpd/) on 2014-10-01**:
Thanks for the answer.  That's what I needed.  If I hadn't been so lazy and willing to just ask the question, where could I have found that myself?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-10-01**:
`catkin_make` implicitly performs the same logic as `catkin_init_workspace`. Calling it manually is never necessary.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-10-01**:
@Dirk Thomas: I wasn't sure without looking it up. Updated answer again.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-10-01**:
@wpd: I'm not sure whether this is actually ROS specific. catkin is essentially CMake, so i just used that knowledge and extrapolated a bit.